# How to select rows multiple times from a data frame if it appears multiple times in a list, without changing the column order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-preprocessing

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
data = {'Date': ['22-08-2021', '12-09-2021', '02-10-2021', '22-11-2021'], 'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'O'], 'Item':['Apple','Banana','Carrot', 'Orange'], 'Cost':[10, 12, 15, 13]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe
```

[image]

And a list of indices,

```
index_list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'O', 'C', 'C']
```

And I want to select rows, based on their indices, multiple times as they appear in this list, so that the above dataframe would become

```
data2 = {'Date':['22-08-2021', '22-08-2021', '12-09-2021', '12-09-2021', '22-11-2021', '02-10-2021', '02-10-2021'], 'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'O', 'C', 'C'], 'Item':['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Carrot', 'Carrot'], 'Cost':[10, 10, 12, 12, 13, 15, 15]}
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
dataframe2
```

[image]

What's the best way to do this using Pandas?

**My approach:**

I wrote the following for loop to achieve this, but I think there should be inbuilt pandas functions to do this in a much more elegant and efficient way.

```
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = dataframe.columns)
for i in index_list:
    idx = dataframe.index[dataframe['ID'] == i]
    dataframe2 = pd.concat([dataframe2, dataframe.loc[idx]])
dataframe2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reset_index()` to add the index as a normal column, then `set_index()` and `.loc[]` to fetch rows by ID. Then once you know the original indexes of the rows you want, you can use `.loc[]` again to get them.

```
>>> orig_indexes = dataframe.reset_index().set_index('ID').loc[index_list, 'index']
>>> dataframe.loc[orig_indexes]
         Date ID    Item  Cost
0  22-08-2021  A   Apple    10
0  22-08-2021  A   Apple    10
1  12-09-2021  B  Banana    12
1  12-09-2021  B  Banana    12
3  22-11-2021  O  Orange    13
2  02-10-2021  C  Carrot    15
2  02-10-2021  C  Carrot    15
```

Comment: Can you add `.reset_index()`, so it's the same as the OP's expected output?

Comment: Your method changes the column order if done on columns other than the first column, which I don't want.

Comment: You can avoid the change of column order by retaining the original dataframe, and using the indexes of the selected rows to select them. See edit.